# Associating subclasses with ints and other Data in Java

Tags: java, class, inheritance

Let's say I want to make a class to represent polygons, for example.  And I wanted to make subclasses to represent specific shapes like triangles, quadrilaterals, or Pentagons.

This means that I will have classes that implement polygon that have a natural association with an integer.  Is there a way I can represent this in my code?  I guess what I really want is something similar to generics, except that they take numbers as arguments.  For example, it would be nice if I could say something like Polygon<4> to refer to quadrilateral.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a factory with a method which returns object of the type you need depending on the number of vertices.

Something like PolygonFactory.createPolygon(numberOfVertices).

Comment: That's more or less what I said; I think it's just a matter of Java's type system not doing what the OP wants it to. Plus you'd need an infinite number of subclasses ;)

Comment: I suppose that is the way it has to work.  I could just make an enum to associate subtypes with numbers.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yup, either infinite number of subclasses or, like in your case, only one class with parametrized instances.

Answer (score 0):

That would need to be a constructor argument, like "numberOfSides".

Comment: Yes, but I want numberOfSides to be part of what class it is.  Is that possible?

Comment: @Joe Maybe, but I don't know how (without subclassing/interfaces/etc which I think would defeat the purpose of what you'd like to do). Generics are about types, not values.

Comment: No.  I want subclasses.  I want the Triangle to be a different "thing" than a pentagon.

Comment: @Joe And I'm saying without concrete implementations you can't do that.